# How do Rails views get access to concerns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, separation-of-concerns

I've been learning Rails and seems like concerns are a way to dry up fat models and make methods sharable by models. I'm confused though as to why views/partials have access to these methods. Shouldn't the MVC model make all the model related things go through the controller and then be given to the view. It feels like giving views access directly to model concerns skips the controller. Also why do I not have access to these methods in Rails console?

Answer (score 1):

A model concern can be seen as a way to split up a model with many methods. It is possible to share common methods between models, but also possible to just thin out the model code.

Once you include the concern, all concern methods are mixed into the model, and therefore are available anywhere the 'base' model methods are.

Comment: So would it be correct to say that views have access to model methods because the controller gets it from the model and passes it to the view to use if necessary?

Comment: Yes that is correct. An "instance variable", ie: starting with '@' is usually an instance of a model, which is sent from the controller to the view.